# Cannot resolve method/symbol in fragment when trying to get method from viewmodel

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-room

I'm new to programming and have a problem.
I'm trying to get some value from room database.

The problem is when I try to get the method from viewModel to my fragment, android studio cannot resolve symbol.

my fragment:

```
public class Tab1Frag extends Fragment {
private Tab1FragModelView tab1ViewModel;
private RoomDatabase db;


public Tab1Frag() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


 db = TransactionRoomDatabase.getDatabase(this);
    //problem here

    tab1ViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(Tab1FragModelView.class);
    tab1ViewModel.todaySum();
    //and here

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);
}
```

The android studio underlined getApplicationContext on db as cannot resolve method and transactionEntity on tab1ViewModel.todaySum as cannot resolve symbol.

I don't know what the problem is because there's no problem in my another activity

here is a section of that activity

```
db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), TransactionRoomDatabase.class,
            "transactionEntity").build();

    addSpendingDetailText = findViewById(R.id.addSpendingDetailText);

    inputViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(InputViewModel.class); //important

    Button addSpending = findViewById(R.id.addSpendingBtn);
    addSpending.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String transactionDetail = addSpendingDetailText.getText().toString();
            String transactionAmount = hiddenAmount.getText().toString();
            String transactionCategory = chooseCategory.getText().toString();
            String transactionDate = hiddenDateText.getText().toString();

            //Handler if field empty
            if (transactionDetail.trim().isEmpty() || transactionAmount.trim().isEmpty() ||
                    transactionCategory.trim().isEmpty() || transactionDate.trim().isEmpty()) {
                Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(InputSpending.this,
                        "Please insert all required data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM,
                        0, 275);
                toast1.show();
                return;
            }

            else {TransactionEntity transactionEntity = new TransactionEntity(transactionDate,
                    transactionCategory, transactionDetail, Double.parseDouble(transactionAmount)) {
            };
            inputViewModel.insert(transactionEntity);
```

I don't know if this gonna be needed or not, but i'll just post it just in case

my DAO

```
@Insert
void insertTransaction(TransactionEntity transactionEntity);

class SumToday { public double total;
}

@Query("SELECT SUM(transactionAmount) as total FROM `transaction` where date(transactionDate = 'now')")
double getTodayDateValue();
```

my fragment viewmodel

```
public class Tab1FragModelView extends AndroidViewModel {
    private TransactionRepository repository;

    public Tab1FragModelView(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new TransactionRepository(application);
    }

    public void todaySum(){
        repository.todaySum();
    }
}
```

my Repository

```
public class TransactionRepository {
private TransactionDao transactionDao;

public TransactionRepository(Application application) {
    TransactionRoomDatabase db;
    db = TransactionRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
    transactionDao = db.transactionDao();
}


public void insert(TransactionEntity transactionEntity) {
    new InsertTransactionAsyncTask(transactionDao).execute(transactionEntity);
}
private static class InsertTransactionAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<TransactionEntity, Void, Void> {
    private TransactionDao transactionDao;
    private InsertTransactionAsyncTask(TransactionDao transactionDao) {
        this.transactionDao = transactionDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(TransactionEntity... transactions) {
        transactionDao.insertTransaction(transactions[0]);
        return null;
    }
}


 public void todaySum() {
        new TodaySumAsyncTask(transactionDao).execute();
    }
    private static class TodaySumAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<TransactionEntity, Void, Double> {
        private TransactionDao transactionDao;
        private TodaySumAsyncTask(TransactionDao transactionDao) {
            this.transactionDao = transactionDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(TransactionEntity... transactions) {
            Double data = transactionDao.getTodayDateValue();
            Log.d("TAG", "doInBackground: data :"+data);
            // use livedata to notify viewmodel and then ui
            return data;
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

+adding information:

My goal is to show the sum of value/amount from the database to my fragment's textView, no less no more.

To do that I'm trying to access it with viewmodel, which connect to repository, which connect to database. Then, I get this "cannot resolve symbol" error which is not happen when I'm inserting data to database. I've tried copying the working code of insert method to this fragment and it showing same "cannot resolve symbol" error. The only differences is I use that insert method in an activity, not fragment. I don't know if that the problem or not, but it maybe worth mentioning.

So far the apps is working until inserting data to database. When I check the database, the inputted data is there.

I don't mind changing my code as long as it can get my goal, but please don't put too advance code (because I'm still new to programming).

Comment: Why in oncreateview() has direct dB initialization?

Comment: ah, is it not needed? i thought it's need to initialize if i want to access it.

Comment: @ObedAdhinatapraya He just meant, that you need to incapsulate all logic as much as possible. By moving this DB work (called as Model) in the ViewModel. Back to your question, you need to extend Tab1FragModelView from simply ViewModel (without paramters).

Comment: @GensaGames I've tried to change the extend at Tab1FragModelView from AndroidViewModel to ViewModel, and delete the word "application" from super, but the problem is still persist. Or do I must change anything else in Tab1FragModelView?

Comment: I don't sure, what is wrong, from your implementation, but problem is not in instantiating the ViewModel. So need to check all the code. Do you have it in Github.

Comment: @GensaGames to elaborate, the apps is working fine without error in term of inserting data to database. I've check the database too, there's some data there. Then i have this problem when i want to show sum of value in fragment. My goal is displaying that sum value to textview in fragment.

Comment: @ObedAdhinatapraya edited the code , and tried on my machine it works. please have a look

Comment: @AshokKumar I've tried copy your edit, but now theres problem at db = TransactionRoomDatabase.getDatabase(this); underlining "this". and there's problem too in my repository at TodaySumAsyncTask.

Comment: @AshokKumar do you mean Tab1FragModelView.java? I've tried it and the problem is still same. Note: what I did is copying your edit at my tab1Frag.java, deleting param from method and extend AndroidViewModel at Tab1FragModelView.java, deleting some params at TransactionRepository.java

Comment: @ObedAdhinatapraya have a look on my edited code, app will run fine.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Hello @AshokKumar, sorry for slow response. I still try to learn and experimenting with liveData, and just now i succeed to implement it. You should make an answer of it. While there's another query problem, my goal to show data from datbase to textview has finally achieved. Thanks for your help

Comment: Did the edited answer help you ?if yes approve the edit

Comment: I've approve it, but why edit the question? why not make an answer?